# Working with unique thread in Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, multithreading, apache, tomcat

**ENVIRONMENT**
We use apache tomcat to comunicate a ***visual layer (actionscript - flex)*** to the ***business layer (java)***. This comunication is used for lots of requests, the visual ask for data in the DB, and lots of operations.

**THE PROBLEM**
The problem is that we are interacting with *a camera that only supports one session simultaneosly*, and as far as i know *apache tomcat create lots of threads*, which are trying to comunicate with the camera at the same time.

Maybe you are thinking that its a bad implementation that we made, but the problem is that there is a functionality (the live view *-showing images directly like recording video-*) which makes imposible to release the camera after asking for the instant picture.

**BEING MORE ESPECIFIC**
**In all the others method which interact to the cam, there is no problem beacause we make the follow steps:**

*1-oppen session with the cam

2-make whatever with the cam

3-release the cam*

This steps works fine with almost all the methods (like taking pictures or downloading theme to the pc), but for the live view, we cant oppen a session and closing it every time (beacuase it makes an important delay, and the camera needs tobe ready), so we have to leave the session oppened while the live view, the procedure is something like this:

**First live view pic**
*1-oppen session with cam

2-download live view pic*

**Second and next pics**
*1-download live view pic*

**Final live view pic**
*1-download live view pic

2-release the cam*

In the first time when we are working with a simple thread all works fine, but if after other calls, new threads were created, and **two treads try to do live view** (one oppened session and the other wants to interact with the cam), the tomcat get freezed...

**CONCLUSION**
**The problem we have is that Tomcat creates lots of thread when java comunicate with the visual layer, but if the thread want to access to the camera and the session was oppened for another, tomcat get freezed...**

**THE QUESTION

There is a way to make apache tomcat works with an especific thread for a call to a java method???**

**NOTE**
We debug and try all the methods in easy eclipse working with one thread and everything works fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The solution i found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761618/why-is-my-tomcat-6-executor-thread-pool-not-being-used-by-the-connector)

The solution i found is using the code in other question, now i have only one thread alive, maybe this solution can generate some delay problems...

Comment: Other aproach is to set the idle time live of the Threads to 20 miliseconds, so there wont be two thread alive at the time i start the live view...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the threads Tomcat uses. The problam is with the absence of exclusive access to the camera. You should use a Semaphore (with a unique permit), acquire a permit when opening the session with the camera, and release the permit when releasing the session with the camera.

This way, all the threads will be blocked until they can acquire the permit. Semaphore can handle timeouts or can try to acquire the permit, so a thread wanitng to access the camera can still answer with an error message if some other thread uses it.

Comment: thaks you for the answer, this is an interesting tip, do you know where i can get information about Semaphore and how to implement it... the implementation is in java or is in tomcat??? i look for the docs api in java but still dont know much about it...

Comment: It's a standard Java class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Comment: OK thanks for your help... let me make some tests and if i came to the solution i will mark that as the correct answer... in other case i will comment something back... thaks for your time!

Comment: i made some test trying the Semaphore solution, but the problem i have is: how i could make that the thread wich was connected to the cam, would interact with it again? I could ensure that only the thread which open the session could talk to the cam, but its guaranted that tomcat will re-use it???

Comment: It does not really matter which thread uses the cam if you make sure every time the cam is used, a permit to the semaphore is acquired before using it, and relased after using it.

Comment: yep you are right, we make all the method to ensure that every thread open a session and then close it, but in the live view method this is impossible because it generate a delay that cant be allowed for this funtionality. For this reason we have to deal with the threads concurrence...

Comment: If I understand correctly, the "download live view pic" action is only accessible to the user if a session has been opened before for this user. And the user can't start several "download live view pic" actions in parallel. So if the user can download live view pic, it means that he already has the semaphore permit. So everything should be OK. You just have to make sure that he releases the permit some time.

Comment: The problem is that the download live view pic method return a real time picture and must be called lots of time, and if in this calls a thread that hasnt oppened the session try to download the live view pc, all get freezed....

Comment: So in fact, the problem is that the camera is usable by only one thread. If so, you should use all the camera accesses in a dedicated unique thread, and ask this unique thread to perform all the operations with the camera. Consider using an ExecutorService, passing Callables to this executor, and getting the results using the returned Future.

Comment: Ok thats an interesting idea lets me take a look abouts ExecutorService... Thanks you so much!!!